# UIContextMenuConfiguration shows multiple table view rows

Tags: ios, swift, uicontextmenuconfiguration

I have tableview with sections, items grouped by sections. Trying to present context menu:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
            UIMenu(title: "", children: [
                UIAction(title: R.string.localizable.delete(), image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive) { _ in
                ...
                }
            ])
        }
    }
```

In presented menu I have multiple items, which have animations between them, but I need only one selected. Sometimes it animated between two items, sometimes only one item appear(as expected).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain/show "Sometimes it animated between two items" ?

Comment: check above two screens, caption for message changed from 'норм' to 'Давай скатаем' in loop.